# Click all links on page containing string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a function to a toolbar Chrome extension I've made. What I'd like it to do is once a navigate to a particular page I'd like be able to push a button on the tool bar and have it "click" all of the links on that page containing harvest.game?user=123456 with 123456 being a different number for all of the links. It could be using jquery or javascript. The only catch is that the script will need to be inserted as an element to the head of the page as cross domain scripting is not allowed so no external references to a js file. I can handle the adding of the element but, I'm having no luck figuring out the actual function.

The elements containing the links all look like this:

```
<div class="friendWrap linkPanel">
<h5>Christine...</h5>
<div class="friend-icon">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/100001726475148/picture"></div>
<div class="levelBlock friend-info">
<p>level</p>
<h3 class="level">8</h3></div>
<a href="harvest.game?user=701240" class="btn">Harvest</a>
<a class="boxLink" href="profile.game?user_id=701240"><span></span></a></div>
```

Something like this (I know this is a mess and doesn't work)? OR maybe something BETTER using jquery?

```
var rlr=1;
function harvestall(){var frt,rm,r,rld,tag,rl;
var frt=1000;
r=document.getElementsByClassName("friendWrap linkPanel");
rl=r.length;
rld=rl-rlr;
if(rld>=0){tag=r[rld].getElementsByTagName('a');
if (rl>=1 {rlr++;harvestall();}
else if (rl>=1) {tag[1].onclick();do something??? ;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
$("a[href*='harvest.game?user=']").trigger("click");
```

Comment: So adding it to the head of the page is resulting in harvestLinks is not defined  :-(
`FJ1=document.createElement("script");
    FJ1.type="text/javascript";
    FJ1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("$(function harvestLinks($){$(\"a[href*='harvest.game?user=']\").trigger(\"click\");});"));
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(FJ1);`

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement Get rid of the $(); surrounding the function and the parameter $ then it should work.

Comment: Please see the following for performance considerations: http://jsperf.com/jquery-complex-selector-vs-filter

Answer (score 0):

```
// Using jQuery, wait for DOMReady ...
$(function harvestLinks() {

  // Only create regexp once ...
  var reURL = /harvest.game\?user=/,

      // Create a ref variable for harvest links ...
      // Use 'links' later without querying the DOM again.
      links = $("a").filter(
        function() {
          // Only click on links matching the harvest URL ...
          return this.href && reURL.test(this.href);
        }
      ).click();

});
```

Comment: So should I then be able to append it to the head by using this?

Comment: FJ1=document.createElement("script");
    FJ1.type="text/javascript";
    FJ1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("$(function harvestLinks($) {var reURL=/harvest.game\?user=/,links = $('a[href]').filter(function() {return reURL.test(this.href);}).click();});"));
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(FJ1);

Comment: For greatest efficiency, I've removed the attribute selector and created a compound return statement. Ryan's answer is also very good, but I'm going to run some jsperf.com tests now to confirm my suspicion that a tag lookup with filter function may be quicker than using a complex selector lookup in jQuery.